# DHTLX Scheduler. How to show on eventbox text from Multiselect labels?

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx-scheduler

My snippet - [link](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/4a56853a)
I need get labels of multiselect checkbox's, but i get only key numbers.. How get labels? Thank you advance

P.S. I try this way [enter link description here](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/a925a223) but i get only one label and when i checked 2 and more checkbox ex.text not changed..

Answer (score 0):

You should get the label value in array based on key value. Go through the array with 'for' cycle and compare key in users array and keys selected in the lightbox.

```
if(key == users[i].key)
```

[See example here](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/40392171)